# Lucene : Delete by ID not working

Tags: java, search, indexing, lucene

I am working on integrating Lucene into our project. Currently I have no issues with saving and searching, but delete by id is not working. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Saving code :

```
  @Override
    public void saveIndexes(String text,String filePath, long groupId, boolean type, int objectId)

    Directory directory = org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(path);
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
            IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
            doc.add(new TextField("id",String.valueOf(objectId),Field.Store.YES));
  indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
            indexWriter.commit();
            indexWriter.close();
            directory.close();
}
```

Delete code :

```
 @Override
    public void deleteById(long groupId,int objectId, boolean type) {
        try {
            Path path = //Path to index directory;
            Directory directory = org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(path);
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
            IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
            indexWriter.deleteDocuments(new Term("id",String.valueOf(objectId)));
            indexWriter.commit();
            indexWriter.close();
            directory.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propably because you're using a Textfield for indexing your ID. Use a Stringfield for indexing an ID.

Reason: Stringfields are not going to be tokenized as the doc said so:

> A field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire String value is indexed as a single token. For example this might be used for a 'country' field or an 'id' field

see here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html

Comment: Should I use an IntField instead? Does the deletion code remain the same when I use an IntField?

Comment: Which lucene version do you use? 
There is an IntPoint field in Lucene 6.4.1 which i use but this is only used for range or normal query purpose.
Have you tried with StringField? this should work.

Comment: I have Lucene 5.4.1. Do you mean for deletion I use a stringField or for saving?

Comment: try doc.add(new StringField("id",String.valueOf(objectId),Field.Store.YES)); for indexing. deletion should work like how you wrote it.